# Transform XML structure using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to transform an XML structure  with XSLT.

```
 <detaileddescription>
   <para>Some text</para>
   <para>
    <bold>Title</bold>
   </para>
   <para>Intro text:
    <itemizedlist>
     <listitem>
      <para>Text</para>
     </listitem>
     <listitem>
      <para>Text</para>
     </listitem>
    </itemizedlist>
   </para>
 </detaileddescription>
```

This is what I want:

```
 <detaileddescription>
   <para>Some text</para>
   <List>
    <Title>Title</Title>
    <Intro>
      Intro text:
    </Intro
    <ListItem>
      <para>Text</para>
     </ListItem>
     <ListItem>
      <para>Text</para>
     </ListItem>
    </List>
 </detaileddescription>
```

So in my own words:
If there is a `<bold>` inside a `<para>`, check if the following-sibling of the `<para>` is also a `<para>` and has a child `<para>Text</para>` than I want to rebuild the structure as shown.

I'm not sure if it is possible, because I have just started using xslt/xpath. Can anyone give me a little help?

Comment: This question is really too broad to effectively answer.  Spend a little time reading up on XSLT templates, and the `following-sibling::` and `descendant::` axes.  Maybe then you can reformulate it more specifically with what issue's you're having.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Maybe my question was a little unspecific.
At first I would like to find a test for this:
"Is the first following-sibling of element A an element A with a child B".

Comment: `following-sibling::*[1][self::A[B]]` checks whether the first following sibling element is an `A` element that has at least one `B` element child. Note that in your sample the inner `para` is not a child of the outer `para`, it is only a descendant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use conditions on nodes then I would suggest to put them into match patterns:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="detaileddescription/para[bold][following-sibling::*[1][self::para[.//para]]]">
       <List>
           <Title>
               <xsl:value-of select="bold"/>
           </Title>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"  mode="intro-list"/>
       </List>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="detaileddescription/para[.//para][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::para[bold]]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="detaileddescription/para/text()[1]" mode="intro-list">
        <Intro>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Intro>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="listitem" mode="intro-list">
        <ListItem>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ListItem>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtK/2 for a sample.